# Django CORS request external redirect not allowed

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, django-cors-headers

I faced a problem during send GET request to a django view from react, and those view redirect to GOOGLE_AUTH_ENDPOINT., and this url hit a callback function. But after request from react, it give this error:
Access to fetch at "google auth url" (redirected from 'localhost:8000') from origin 'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

**view**

```
class Glogin(APIView):
    params = {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'response_type': 'code',
        'scope': 'openid email profile',
        'redirect_uri': CALLBACK_DOMAIN,
        'state': state,
    }
    
    if APPS_DOMAIN:
        params['hd'] = APPS_DOMAIN
    
    def get(self,request):
        request.session['googleauth_csrf'] = state
        request.session['next'] = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None)
        print('Here')
        print(urlencode(self.params))
        return HttpResponseRedirect("%s?%s" % (GOOGLE_AUTH_ENDPOINT, urlencode(self.params)))
        #data = {'link':GOOGLE_AUTH_ENDPOINT, 'params':self.params}
        #return Response(data)
```

**ReactJs**

```
  static GLogIn() {
    return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/glogin/", {
      //method: "POST",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      //body: JSON.stringify(body),
    }).then((response) => response.json());
  }
```

**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('auth/', obtain_auth_token),
    path('login/',views.LogInViewSet.as_view()),
    path('logout/',views.LogOutViewSet.as_view()),
    path('articles/',views.ArticlesView.as_view()),
    path('articles/<int:pk>/',views.ArticlesView.as_view()),
    path('glogin/',views.Glogin.as_view()),
    path('callback/',views.Callback.as_view(), name='googleauth_callback'),

    #path('articales/',views.ArticlesViewSet.as_view())
]
```

**settings.py**

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
    #'accounts.google.com',
    #'accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2'
    
)


CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

Comment: Quick hack would be using third party browser plugins to exempt CORS. If you are using Chrome browser then consider installing any good CORS plugin from Chrome store. Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: I use 'Moesif Origin & CORS Changer' this plugin, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Put a hosts entry in the /etc/hosts file for 127.0.0.1

`127.0.0.1 myfakedomain.local`

Then add this to the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST

`'myfakedomain.local:8000',`

Then you can access cors redirects. Chrome blocks them unless they are on special domains. Especially localhost.

Then send your browser to `http://myfakedomain.local:8000`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't get your point clearly, can you give me an example, please?

Comment: I am not sure which part is unclear. Where you are using 127.0.0.1 in your configs, change that to myfakedomain.local